# Message Queues: Per Message Guarantees

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, apache-kafka

We have an option of Kafka and Rabbit MQ and are ok with at least once semantics.

With Rabbit we can have acks per message

With Kafka we can control the offsets with both the High Level and Simple Consumer.

We do not want replaying capabilities and the throughput is low, so either of the two can be used. There is no complex message routing involved.

Based on what factors should one choose either of the queues with the above given requirements.

Thanks

Comment: Installation requirements (for example Kafka requires ZooKeeper), maintainability, system footprint... Or simply, because both are great, the one with which you are more confident

Answer (score 0):

**RabbitMQ:** If your throughput (20k+/sec) is low and you want per-message delivery guarantees go for RabbitMQ

**Kafka:** if you are looking for high throughput(100k+/sec) with no guaranty in message delivery then better go for [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/).

More [here](http://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-for-durable-messaging-with-good-query-features-RabbitMQ-or-Kafka)